# Concating similar keys values into one string

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I'm trying to concat data that have similar key names into string separated by `,`.
What I mean by similar keys is:

```
name.0.id
name.1.id
...
```

Basically I have an array of array.

```
[
  [array(6)]
  [array(9)]
  [array(10)]
]
```

the arrays look like the following:

```
[
    [
        "id",
        10
    ],
    [
        "group_name",
        "Test"
    ],
    [
        "admin",
        "Nobody"
    ],
    [
        "email_address",
        "nobody@nobody.com"
    ],
    [
        "org.id",
        4
    ],
    [
        "created_by.email",
        "nobo@nob.com"
    ]
],
[
    [
        "id",
        8
    ],
    [
        "group_name",
        "Datass"
    ],
    [
        "admin",
        "me2@me2.com"
    ],
    [
        "email_address",
        "me@me.com"
    ],
    [
        "org.id",
        11
    ],
    [
        "created_by.email",
        "me@me.com"
    ],
    [
        "students.0.email",
        "nilton@hh.com"
    ],
    [
        "students.1.email",
        "s@hh.com"
    ],
    [
        "names.0.id",
        13
    ],
    [
        "names.1.id",
        35
    ]
]
```

I have a fixed keys that have all the keys I need, like:

```
const fixed = [
    "id",
    "group_name",
    "admin",
    "email_address",
    "org.id",
    "created_by.email",
    "students",
    "names"
]
```

I would need to get those arrays and create a new array, with the same size as the fixed keys array, but the data that contains `0.id` or `1.id` ... will be concataned into string separated by commas. And if the array that is being filtered doens't contain that data, I will insert an empty string
This is what I'm attempting:

```
[
    [
        "id",
        10
    ],
    [
        "group_name",
        "Test"
    ],
    [
        "admin",
        "Nobody"
    ],
    [
        "email_address",
        "nobody@nobody.com"
    ],
    [
        "org.id",
        4
    ],
    [
        "created_by.email",
        "nobo@nob.com"
    ],
    [
        "students",
        ""
    ],
    [
        "names",
        ""
    ],
],
[
    [
        "id",
        8
    ],
    [
        "group_name",
        "Datass"
    ],
    [
        "admin",
        "me2@me2.com"
    ],
    [
        "email_address",
        "me@me.com"
    ],
    [
        "org.id",
        11
    ],
    [
        "created_by.email",
        "me@me.com"
    ],
    [
        "students",
        "nilton@hh.com,s@hh.com"
    ],
    [
        "names",
        "13,35"
    ],
]
```

I Have used regex to match the names:

```
/(names)(.)([0-9])(.)(id)($)/.test(key)
```

Comment: `name.0.id` is invalid. Do you mean `name[0].id` instead?

Comment: It is `name.0.id` not `name[0].id`, it will always come as `{name}.{number}.id

Comment: It is because of the formattation from the read of the file, it comes as `.{number}.` I have used regex to find a match

Comment: Only `names` and `students` are following this pattern, aren't they? @NiltonSchumacherF

Comment: @NickVu There can be other values, but the will have the following syntax: 
`{someName}.{number}.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```js
const extractData = (data, fields) => data.map(d => {
  const obj = Object.fromEntries(d)
  const keys = Object.keys(obj)

  return fields.map(key => [
    key,
    keys.filter(k => k.startsWith(key)).map(k => obj[k]).join(',')
  ])
})

const fixed = [
  "id",
  "group_name",
  "admin",
  "email_address",
  "org.id",
  "created_by.email",
  "students",
  "names"
]


const data = [
  [
    [
      "id",
      10
    ],
    [
      "group_name",
      "Test"
    ],
    [
      "admin",
      "Nobody"
    ],
    [
      "email_address",
      "nobody@nobody.com"
    ],
    [
      "org.id",
      4
    ],
    [
      "created_by.email",
      "nobo@nob.com"
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      "id",
      8
    ],
    [
      "group_name",
      "Datass"
    ],
    [
      "admin",
      "me2@me2.com"
    ],
    [
      "email_address",
      "me@me.com"
    ],
    [
      "org.id",
      11
    ],
    [
      "created_by.email",
      "me@me.com"
    ],
    [
      "students.0.email",
      "nilton@hh.com"
    ],
    [
      "students.1.email",
      "s@hh.com"
    ],
    [
      "names.0.id",
      13
    ],
    [
      "names.1.id",
      35
    ]
  ]
]



console.log(extractData(data, fixed))
```